# Enter to select and activate href link

Tags: javascript, html

I have setup an autocomplete searchbar with jquery. When I type a part of a searchterm the suggestions pop-up, when I click the suggestion I get redirected to a new page (of the suggestion) which is good.

The problem I have is when I type the a part of a searchterm or the full searchterm there is no action.

What I want is: When I type a searchterm or a part of a searchterm and I press Enter I get redirected to the page of the first suggestion. When I press hover over the suggestion press Enter right now, the first suggestion just comes up in the searchbar.

How can I go about this?

Javascript code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

$(function() {
  var projects = [{
    label: "Bitcoin (BTC)",
    icon: "./alt/alt_logo/bitcoin.png",
    href: "./alt/alt_info/bitcoin.html"
  }, {
    label: "Ethereum (ETH)",
    icon: "./alt/alt_logo/ethereum.png",
    href: "./alt/alt_logo/bitcoin.png"
  }, {
    label: "Litecoin (LTC)",
    icon: "./alt/alt_logo/litecoin.png",
    href: "./alt/alt_logo/bitcoin.png"
  }, {
    label: "Cardano (ADA)",
    icon: "./alt/alt_logo/cardano.png",
    href: "./alt/alt_logo/bitcoin.png"
  }];  

  $(".field_values").autocomplete({
    source: projects,
    create: function() {
      $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li>')
          .append('<a href="' + item.href + '"><img class="icon" src="' + item.icon + '" />' + item.label + '<br>'  + '</a>')
          .appendTo(ul);
      };
    }
  });
});
```

PS: Dont mind the wrong `href` in var `projects`

EDIT:

When I  submit the form by pressing enter or hitting the button. The page reloads but stays on the same page.

HTML:

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <form id="submitsearch">
        <input class="field_values"  id="autocomplete" placeholder="Search..."/>
        <button type="submit" id="searchbutton" class="icon" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I also tried `<form action="./js/searchbar.js">` but that just sends me to a webpage with the javascript displayed on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `autoFocus: true,` to the `autocomplete`
so that it becomes:

```
$("#field_values").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: projects,
```

This only puts the data into the form field.

---

To handle the data, you will need to do the following:

1. Wrap the input in a `form` tag
2. Make sure you have a submit button in the form

You will then be able to hit enter to fill in the field and you will have to hit enter again to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I did dig a little deeper and found the  'autoFocus:true,'. Thanks anyways! Now it takes always selects the first suggestion that appears, when I press Enter now, the suggestion just appears in the searchbar and I dont get redirected to the href/new page. Do you know how I could make that possible?

Comment: Yes, that autofocus only puts the data into the form field.

Comment: Thank you I still got some issues I have edited my question I hope you can take a look at it

Comment: You need to add `action="xxx"` like you mention but replace the xxx with the page/controller that will receive your posted data.